# How to send All-Notes-Off ALSA MIDI Event?

Tags: sound, programming, midi

I am writing a MIDI sequencer in C++ using asoundlib. Sometimes I would like my application to stop all voices, calling an All-Notes-Off event. I do it by calling a note-off to every note at every channel, since this is the only way I know, but for some reasons I am not really happy to send 16*128=2048 events in one moment. Is there any other approach to that? It would be perfect if I could send an event to the control queue, is there any? If not, then what is the way it should be done?

Any help is welcome, since the Internet lacks a good, detailed ALSA documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [crash course on the midi specification](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/midi.html) you simply send an event 'Z' with an all notes off which is explained as `00 B0 7B 00`

```
00 to indicate no time delay
B0 to send a midi control signal
7B to send an all notes off
00 does nothing (padding)
```

You can see a list of midi control bytes here: [MIDI Controller Numbers](http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/etext/MIDI/chapter3_MIDI6.shtml)

Happy hunting!